# Not sure how to sort this JSON Object jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

Sample String:

```
var output = { 
      "myservices":[
         {"name":"oozie", "hostidn": "1", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
         {"name":"oozie", "hostidn": "2", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
         {"name":"oozie", "hostidn": "3", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
         {"name":"oozie", "hostidn": "4", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
         {"name":"oozie", "hostidn": "5", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
         {"name":"single-namenode", "hostidn": "2", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"}
]};
```

My Cracker Jack Attempt at doing it.

```
function sortJSONresultsByHost(a,b)
{
    var objectIDA = parseInt(a.hostidn, 10)
    var objectIDB = parseInt(b.hostidn, 10)
    if(objectIDA === objectIDB)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return objectIDA > objectIDB ? 1 : -1;
}
output.myservices.sort(sortJSONresultsByHost);
```

I actually need to figure out how to sort this various ways. Such as by hostidn, by name, by currstatusclass. But I can't figure out the best way to do it. Is there a way to make a function that could do any by choice or would I need to make a set of functions based on which i want to do, if either how? mine above is not working out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sortObjectsByKey(objects, key){
    objects.sort(function() {
        return function(a, b){
            var objectIDA = a[key];
            var objectIDB = b[key];
            if (objectIDA === objectIDB) {
                return 0;
            }
            return objectIDA > objectIDB ? 1 : -1;        
        };
    }());
}

sortObjectsByKey(output.myservices, "hostidn");
console.log(output.myservices);
```

Comment: dont suppose on a different subject with the same object data you would know how I could get the highest hostidn value would you?